# Empty PowerPoint chart size is massive - Why?

Tags: powerpoint

I created a macro that updates around 55 PowerPoint slides, ranging from populating tables to updating line and bar charts. The macro works well, however, for some reason the PowerPoint file size has increased significantly. While working on the macro the size was around 80,000 KB, after making very few minor changes it suddenly close to doubled to 150,000 KB. To find out which slides cause this huge size, I published the slides to see the individual slide sizes and am able to narrow down the problem. Due to the large variety of charts I will focus on one kind.

I have 2 regular line charts on one slide and the size is 5000+ KB! Whenever I delete one of the two, the size is reduced to roughly half the size.

I have taken the following steps to try to find the problem:
1) Removed and deleted all cells that the chart references to (inside the PowerPoint) -- No change in file size.
2) Removed all chart features, such as axis title, legends, etc -- No change in file size.
3) Slide is not macro enabled and has therefore no macro included in the file.
4) Made sure there are no hidden objects.

All that is left is an empty 'Chart Placeholder' with no data in the XL file and yet the size is very large. 
The PowerPoint slide contains no images either. A regular PowerPoint slide with a line chart should only have a size of around 50-100 KB and I am not sure how the chart has such a massive size.

First time posting my question here! Hopefully someone can help out.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I finally was able to find the problem. For some reason, all charts had the maximum number of rows open (1+ million rows) making the file size that large!

I added: `wb.worksheets(1).UsedRange`to the end of each procedure and now the entire file size is around 4000 KB!

Thank you.